# How can I manually add libraries glfw and glad using g++ (fix undefined reference error)?

Tags: c++, windows, linker, g++

I am getting **undefined reference** errors when trying to compile my program with other libraries. What g++ command do I need to use to compile my program?

I am trying to follow along to learnopengl, https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Creating-a-window. I can't seem to add the libraries **glad** and **glfw** correctly. Most search results show how to add libraries in Visual Studio; however, I am trying to understand the compiling and linking process, so that I can use the text editor of my choice.

I have mingw64 compiler installed on my windows 10 machine with g++ working. I have downloaded the libraries glad and glfw, and I placed the libraries at `C:\cpp_lib`. Below is the file tree from that location.

```
C:\cpp_lib
├───glad
│   ├───include
│   │   ├───glad
│   │   │       glad.h
│   │   │
│   │   └───KHR
│   │           khrplatform.h
│   │
│   └───src
│           glad.c
│
└───glfw
    │   LICENSE.md
    │   README.md
    │
    ├───include
    │   └───GLFW
    │           glfw3.h
    │           glfw3native.h
    │
    ├───lib-mingw-w64
    │       glfw3.dll
    │       libglfw3.a
    │       libglfw3dll.a
    │
    ├───lib-static-ucrt
    │       glfw3.dll
    │       glfw3dll.lib
    │
    ├───lib-vc2012
    │       glfw3.dll
    │       glfw3.lib
    │       glfw3dll.lib
    │       glfw3_mt.lib
    │
    ├───lib-vc2013
    │       glfw3.dll
    │       glfw3.lib
    │       glfw3dll.lib
    │       glfw3_mt.lib
    │
    ├───lib-vc2015
    │       glfw3.dll
    │       glfw3.lib
    │       glfw3dll.lib
    │       glfw3_mt.lib
    │
    ├───lib-vc2017
    │       glfw3.dll
    │       glfw3.lib
    │       glfw3dll.lib
    │       glfw3_mt.lib
    │
    └───lib-vc2019
            glfw3.dll
            glfw3.lib
            glfw3dll.lib
            glfw3_mt.lib
```

I have a c++ file at `C:\learn_opengl\src\main.cpp` with the following code:

```cpp
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried multiple commands along the lines of this one, and always get **undefined reference** errors when calling glfw functions.

Command:

```sh
g++ -Wall -g src\main.cpp -IC:\cpp_lib\glfw\include -IC:\cpp_lib\glad\include -o dist\main.exe
```

```
C:\learn_opengl>g++ -Wall -g src\main.cpp -IC:\cpp_lib\glfw\include -IC:\cpp_lib\glad\include -o dist\main.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvyjawi.o:C:\learn_opengl/src/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `glfwInit'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvyjawi.o: in function `main':
C:\learn_opengl/src/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\learn_opengl/src/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\learn_opengl/src/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why is it not linking the libraries, and what command/options should I be using?

Comment: where is `-l<libraryname>` and `-L<libary location>`?

Comment: @MarekR the libraries at located at C:\cpp_lib\ and named glfw and glad. I have tried adding `-LC:\cpp_lib\glfw -lglfw -LC:\cpp_lib\glad -lglad`, but then I get `C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglad
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: You added the wrong folder.  Your linker will not search in the folder tree. `-LC:\cpp_lib\glfw` should be `-LC:\cpp_lib\glfw\lib-mingw-w64`

Comment: @drescherjm thanks, using `g++ -Wall -g src\main.cpp -IC:\cpp_lib\glfw\include -IC:\cpp_lib\glad\include -o dist\main.exe -LC:\cpp_lib\glfw\lib-mingw-w64 -lglfw3`, I got a new error `undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status` and if I try adding `-LC:\cpp_lib\glad -lglad` then it goes back to `cannot find -lglad`. Do I need to compile glad first (I see that it only has a .h and .c file)?

Comment: I think for some reason you need to link to the windows api library `Gdi32.lib` related: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-describepixelformat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-describepixelformat)

Comment: @drescherjm ok thanks again, I got the glfw functions working with `g++ -Wall -g src\main.cpp -IC:\cpp_lib\glfw\include -IC:\cpp_lib\glad\include -o dist\main.exe -LC:\cpp_lib\glfw\lib-mingw-w64 -lglfw3 -lgdi32`. However, I still can't use glad functions (not in the main.cpp listed above). I get `undefined reference to 'glad_glClearColor'` when trying to compile this file https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/1.2.hello_window_clear/hello_window_clear.cpp . How do I include that library?

Comment: @drescherjm Got it working once I compiled glad.c to a dll file. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

First, I had to compile glad with the command `g++ -Wall -g -IC:\cpp_lib\glad\include -c -o C:\cpp_lib\glad\glad.dll C:\cpp_lib\glad\src\glad.c`.

Then, I needed to add options for each library including gdi32 `-LC:\cpp_lib\glfw\lib-mingw-w64 -lglfw3 -lgdi32 -LC:\cpp_lib\glad -lglad`.

Comment: The first commands creates an object file (which normally have `.o` extension), renamed to `.dll`. If this actually works, I'm unsure how... The right way to produce a dll is to use `-shared` instead of `-c`.